# How to solve "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source..." for a deb repository?

Tags: 22.04

I installed elastic and kibana 8.4.1 in ubuntu 22.04
and when i try to do

```
sudo apt update
```

or

```
sudo apt install unzip
```

I get this error

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source 

https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/elasticsearch-keyring.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A repository with `deb` packages can be *signed* cryptographically (or rather, the packages coming from this repository can be signed). This is done with a *key* by the person or persons that issued the packages. In order to check the signature, your system needs the key that was used for the signing (more specifically, the *public key* of a private / public key pair).

Previously, the keys for the repositories a system knew about were stored in a central location and managed with the `apt-key` command. This has been deprecated for security reasons. Now the keys are stored in separate so-called *key rings* in the file system. The source entry of the repository refers to the respective keyring by the `Signed-By` option.

So, instead of what used to be a source entry like

```
deb https://some.url.tld/ any main
```

you have the additional option `Signed-By` (and maybe other options as well)

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/some-keyring.gpg] https://some.url.tld/ any main
```

It looks like one of the repository in your sources list uses the `Signed-By` option multiple times, so `apt` doesn't know which key to use to check the signature. Or maybe it's a related problem, but there seems to be a case of conflicting keys.

Comment: yea you right bro thanks i buck to the installation of elastic and i run this cmd and it's work : echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/elasticsearch-keyring.gpg] https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-8.x.list