# Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source *Plex*

Tags: plex

Wondering if somebody could shed some light on a problem I've been having - Ive had a ubuntu server running that was set up as a media server with Plex on command line and its been running 4 years solid. I've been updating it throughout all of the 4 years and trying to understand code which I think I've been fairly successful with but it eventually bricked and I had to reinstall the OS and start again. (Version 22.04.1)

Im trying to install Plex back on the machine but the command I keep getting is as follows and I can't so any updates whatsoever.

```
Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public: /usr/share/keyrings/plex-keyring.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/plex.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I've been searching everywhere for hours and I've not found anything to solve the problem.
if anybody could shed some light I would be very grateful.

Gilly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source..." for a deb repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433527/how-to-solve-conflicting-values-set-for-option-signed-by-regarding-source-f)

Answer (score 1):

The GPG certificate Plex installed on your machine is not a part of the same pair they used to sign their repository. This is most likely due to neglect by Plex themselves, especially since I had this problem too. However, it's good practice to treat errors like this as a security issue. In which case you need to figure out which certificate is the correct one and put it in place.
I recommend just downloading the latest version from Plex and manually installing it while grumbling something uncouth about Plex under your breath.
Also, for me the new installer duplicated a line in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list, so consider checking that file for anything odd looking.